# How to graph a ggplot + geom(line) with several qualitative variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have my data in the survey type and I want to make a graph with ggplot.

for example,

id 1 has passport, visa1 and visa2. So, I want to group o create a variable named the type of document, all this because I wanna graph a type line plot with several series, the series would be passport visa1 and visa2. I really don't know how to do this.

Please, help me.

```
id   date        passport   visa1    visa2

1   feb.2018         x        x       x
5   jan.2000         na       x       na
6   oct.1990         x        na      na
6   sep.2005         na       x       na
7   dec.2018         na       na      x
8   aug.2016         x        x       na
```

Comment: Please share your current approach/code, so that it will help the community to better answer this question

Comment: ggplot(data = data1, aes(x = date, y = id, color=(passport, visa1, visa2), group = date)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()    I was thinking someting like this, but, i dont know it is posible . Thank you!

Comment: Check this advice on how to ask a question to make it easy for people to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data is in wide format. For ggplot2 you need it in long format.
Here is how to collect your binary columns (passport, visa1, visa2) into a single factor variable: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/

Then all you need to do is assign the new variable to a `ggplot2` aesthetic such as `colour`. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/

I am not posting code because I think these are very fundamental knowledge of tidying and visualizing data, and the OP is better served by studying a proper tutorial. It should be easy to synthesize the necessary code from the linked resources.

Also because it is unclear to me how exactly the OP want their data grouped, what should be plotted against what...

EDIT:

It occurred to me that there is one extra step in going from design matrix to long tidy format: After making the long format, you have to dismiss all the rows that have `NA` in your newly created variable.

I guess I'll post some code after all. I don't if this is what you wanted, but maybe it will get you thinking in the correct direction.

```
DF <- data.frame(v1 = letters[1:10],
           v2 = sample(c(0,1), 10, replace=TRUE),
           v3 = sample(c(0,1), 10, replace=TRUE),
           v4 = rnorm(10, 100, 10))

##    v1 v2 v3        v4
## 1   a  0  1  80.87423
## 2   b  0  1 107.77500
## 3   c  0  0  99.93618
## 4   d  1  0  99.77675
## 5   e  0  0  93.72743
## 6   f  0  1 102.19122
## 7   g  0  0  89.06118
## 8   h  1  1 118.87512
## 9   i  0  0  98.09992
## 10  j  1  1 106.06299

library(tidyverse)

DF2 <- DF %>% 
  gather(key="newvar", value="category", c("v2", "v3")) %>%
  filter(category == 1) %>%
  select(-category) # don't need it anymore

##   v1        v4 newvar
## 1  d  99.77675     v2
## 2  h 118.87512     v2
## 3  j 106.06299     v2
## 4  a  80.87423     v3
## 5  b 107.77500     v3
## 6  f 102.19122     v3
## 7  h 118.87512     v3
## 8  j 106.06299     v3


ggplot(DF2, aes(x=v1, y=v4, colour=newvar, group=newvar)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]